# How to assign a custom model type to knockout observable?

Tags: knockout.js

I am returning JsonResult to my view to use with knockout. The result is complex list with nested lists which I want to turn into re3levant knockout models.

I don't know how to assign model types to nested items:

```
var TopViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;    
    self.basketItems = ko.observableArray();

    $.getJSON(myUrl, function (data) {
        console.log(data);

            $.map(data,
                function (item) {
                    self.basketItems.push(new MyItemViewModel([item.Quote], item.ElementHere));
            });
    });
}

var MyItemViewModel = function (quote, elementHere) {
    var self = this;
    self.Quote = ko.observableArray(quote); // this should be of QuoteViewModel type - how to make it?
    self.ElementHere = ko.observable(elementHere);
};

var QuoteViewModel = function (id, ref) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(id);
    self.Ref = ko.observable(ref);
    self.showDiv = ko.observable(false);

    self.toggleDiv = function (item) {
        console.log('Toggled Div window');
        self.showDiv(!self.showDiv());
    }
}
```

How to assing QuoteViewMoel type to self.Quote observable in MyItemViewModel?

Comment: If you have a list of items, that they should be observables, is better use the pluggin (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).  You could use the 'ignore' section of this link to avoid overwrite computed observables or functions like `self.toggleDiv`.

Comment: @JoseLuis if I do `ko.mapping.fromJS(quote, self.Quote)` within MyItemViewModel then I get undefined on `self.Quote.Id` or item `self.Quote.Id()` is not a function

Comment: What's wrong with `self.Quote = ko.observableArray(new QuoteViewModel(quote))`?

Comment: @user3297291 It returns an error `The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined.`

Comment: Ah, I missed that you're trying to create an *array* of `QuoteViewModel`s. I'll write a quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass an array with one item to `MyItemViewModel` here:

```
new MyItemViewModel([item.Quote], /* ... */)
```

Which means `quote` inside the `MyItemViewModel` constructor is an array with a `length` of `1`.

From the looks of your `QuoteViewModel` I'm guessing it's meant to represent *one* quote. So, you can either (a) use a regular observable and not wrap stuff in an array, or (b) transform *each* item in the array to a viewmodel.

#### (A) Going with one quote

```
var MyItemViewModel = function (quote, elementHere) {
    // No longer an array
    this.Quote = ko.observable(new QuoteViewModel(quote.Id, quote.Ref)); 
};

new MyItemViewModel(item.Quote, /* ... */); // No longer wrapped in an array
```

This makes each `MyItemViewModel` have *one, observable* `QuoteViewModel`.

#### (B) Working with an array of quotes

If you do need the `Quote` to be in an array, you have to wrap our constructor call over each item:

```
// This is the snippet from example (A) wrapped in a function
var quoteViewModelFromData = function(quote) {
  return new QuoteViewModel(quote.Id, quote.Ref);
}


var MyItemViewModel = function (quotes, elementHere) {
    this.Quotes = ko.observableArray(quotes.map(quoteViewModelFromData)); 
};

new MyItemViewModel([item.Quote], /* ... */);
```

I'd suggest changing some of the names and data structures. Should it be `item.Quotes`? Should that already be an array? Also:

- Use plural variable names for arrays
- Only use `CapitalizedNames` for constructors

If `item.Quote` is already an array, you shouldn't wrap it in `[]` inside your `MyItemViewModel` call.

Comment: I spoted Quote should not be an array but one of its properties should and wouldn't know about the mapping. Now all is working beautifully. Thank you!